# spring mvc and xforms - can it be done, and if so, with how much pain?

Tags: spring-mvc, xforms

So after alot of fuss and bother I got my Spring MVC webclient to use XSLT to create a ModelAndView of some XML coming from my SOAP web service. Well, I suceeded in submitting a request with no parameters to the service and retrieving a XML document with several nodes which XSLT transmorgifies into a web page with a table with row=node.

But of course now I wish to insert rows into my database. And it sounds like this is a job for XForms. But how does one bake XForms into Spring MVC?

As always, hints, suggestions, links, constructive critism and examples are all welcome and appreciated.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Why did you choose these techniques? That sounds seriously cumbersome. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sometimes I like to take the road less travelled...until I (re)discover that road is less travelled for a reason. Methinks it's time to turn around and get back on the freeway. The brochure said XForms is a superior alternative to HTML forms and maybe that's so but I find precious little info on how to make it work within the Spring framework. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on which XForms implementation you choose, and whether it is entirely client-side, or involves both the client and the server.

In general, it is difficult to mix together multiple technologies which are at some level designed to do the same thing. In my experience, for example, it doesn't make sense to combine XForms with JSF. It sounds like Spring MVC might be a similar case, although I don't know much about Spring MVC.

XForms itself follows an MVC architecture, so you would have to figure out whether that conflicts with Spring's MVC architecture. It may or may not be the case.

There are places where it makes sense to combine other technologies with XForms, however. For example:

- You can use plain JSP (or similar server-side template technology) to generate XForms pages, and let the client (browser with JavaScript XForms implementation) or server/client (hybrid implementation which transforms XForms on the server) process the resulting XForms.
- XForms proper doesn't include a controller (in the sense of routing, pages, etc.). So it makes sense to use a separate controller, client-side or server-side, around pages which use XForms.